# Throwing an exception in constructor (java)

Tags: java, exception, constructor

```
Utwor(String x, String y, Integer z) {
    tytul1 = x;
    wykonawca2 = y;
    rok3 = z;
      if (z < 1900 || z > 2015) {
            System.out.println("Rok utworu musi się zawierać pomiędzy 1900, a 2015.");
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid cents value: " + z);

        }
}
```

z is supposed to be between 1900-2015, and it works. But I don't want my program to completely stop but to ask again for this variable. I'm not sure I'm doing it right way, since my teacher just gave me example code `throw new Exception("Tytuł utworu nie może być pusty!");` and that's it.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Can my program continue after it throws exception?

Comment: yes it can. whatever calls that function needs to handle the thrown exception via a try catch. see here for more on that: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where you call your method Utwor, you have to put it in a try catch block.

```
boolean zIsOk = false;
do{
    try{
      Utwor(x, y, z);
      zIsOk = true;
    }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
      zIsOk = false;
    }
while(!zIsOk)
```

Maybe it's not the best answer, but it works :)

If you have to ask your user to re-enter a z number you can add a Console.ReadLine() in the catch block.

Comment: in software there is rarely a best answer, and almost never one that everyone agrees is best., this one is a good answer and that is what is important